# Jquery/Ajax sometimes fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Have been working on a small project.  For some reason, sometimes my Ajax/JQuery functions don't execute.

For example, I have a button that once you click it, an automatic select/option list is generated from SQL of employee names.  I am setting it up as such:

```
$("#search_prospects_image").one('click', function() {
  var blankData;
  $.post('get_prospects.php', blankData, processData);

  function processData(data) {
    var prospect_names = JSON.parse(data);
    var select = document.getElementById("search_prospects_image");

    for (var i = 0; i < prospect_names.length; ++i) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = prospect_names[i];
      option.value = prospect_names[i];
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
});
```

Occasionally, when I click the button and attempt to select an option, it doesn't list anything.  I need to either refresh the page, or click something else, and then go back to it.

I am not an expert by any means - fairly new at this, so I wouldn't be surprised if I was doing this incorrectly.

If anyone can see anything off the bat that would slow down these calls or sometimes make them fail, I would love to know!  Thanks!

Comment: well did you add an error handler to your Ajax Request and see why it fails?

Comment: Occasional misses on requests are generally caused by limits placed on your hosting. You should check the logs to see what the error is. I would also check to see what the service level of your provider is.

Comment: When it doesn't work, do you see any errors in the console?  Also have you verified in the network tab that the request happened, returned successfully, and returned the data you expected in the format you expected?

Answer (score 3):

You're using `one()`:

> [**Description**: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

So it's only going to fire on the first click.

You probably want `on()`

> [**Description**: Attach an event handler function for one or more events
>   to the selected elements](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

So it will execute the call on each and every click.

As far as your code; I would just reflect that one change:

```
$("#search_prospects_image").on('click', function() {
  var blankData;
  $.post('get_prospects.php', blankData, processData);

  function processData(data) {
    var prospect_names = JSON.parse(data);
    var select = document.getElementById("search_prospects_image");

    for (var i = 0; i < prospect_names.length; ++i) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = prospect_names[i];
      option.value = prospect_names[i];
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I can still grab the data clicking multiple times.  It just sometimes doesn't work.  I used "one" because when I did on click, it kept duplicating the data every click and adding multiple options into the select form.  Is there a way to avoid that?